# Comparing dates in google script

Tags: date, google-apps-script

When I pull a date in from a spreadsheet and use "valueOf" it gives me an integer (ie 1707409320000).  When I use var now = Date(); then now.valueOf(); in google script, it returns "Thu Feb 08 2024 10:31:25 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)" How can I get the two dates to compare?

Answer (score 0):

The values are need to compare must be of the same type: either a date or milliseconds since epoch.  Examples:

```js
// Comparing a date with milliseconds
console.log(new Date().getTime() === 1707409320000);

// Comparing two dates
console.log(new Date() === new Date());

// Comparing a date with milliseconds converted to a date
console.log(new Date() === new Date(1707409320000));
```

Important: new dates must be initialized with `new Date()`.  Calling `Date()` without `new` returns a string instead of a date object ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value)).

Comment: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Options");
  var closeDate = sheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
  Thu Feb 08 2024 10:31:25 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) >>> 1707409320000
  var now = Date();
  Thu Feb 08 2024 10:22:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) >>> Thu Feb 08 2024 10:22:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I couldn't understand where this transformation comes from: `Thu Feb 08 2024 10:31:25 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) >>> 1707409320000`.  If `Options!D5` contains a valid date, Apps Script should return it as a date object.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  When I put now() into cell A1, it returns full date in time (like above) in script editor. When I value of that date, I get an integer.  When I  do var time = Date() in script editor, I get the date and time (like above), BUT when I do value of, it returns the same date and time as above.  It does not give me an integer, thus I can’t compare the two dates.

Comment: In other words, when I do - var time = Date().valueOf(); in google script, its still returning Thu Feb 08 2024 10:22:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) instead of an integer.

Comment: @Dave You need to do `var time = new Date()` instead of `var time = Date()`.  Calling `Date()` without `new` returns a string instead of a date object ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value)).

Comment: @Dave I have updated the answer with this detail.  If your problem is resolved, could you mark the question as resolved, please.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for timestamps that occur on current date

```
function comparingdates() {
  let dt = new Date();
  let dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();//assume these are timestamps
  const ovs = vs.map(([a]) => {
    let d = new Date(a);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()).valueOf();
    //comparing datetimes at 0000 hours between what is in the spreadsheet and comparing them to todays date value at 0000 hours
    return (dv == dtv) ? [a] : [""]; //returns today's time stamp for all rows that match todays date.
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ovs)); //a 2d array of time stamps that occur on today's date
}
```